# Existence of implicit and explicit derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Say we have an implicit function $y(x)$ defined by $f(x,y)=0$. Does the existence of $dy/dx$ on some region of $x$ imply the existence of $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ at $(x,y(x))$? If not, is there any expression we can form for $dy/dx$?

Comment: @Mattos The chain rule requires the partial derivates to exist - so that does not help. In fact $f$ does not even have to be continuous anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider the function $ f(x,y) = | x - y |.$ The set of points where $f = 0$ is precisely the set of points where $y = x$. The function $y(x) = x$ is differentiable, with derivative $1$ for all $x$. Yet $f$ itself does not have well-defined partial derivatives at any point of the form $(x,y(x))$.

Comment: Good example, but you could even have used $\chi_{x\ne y}$, the characteristic function of complement of the line $x=y$. Then you have an example where $f$ isn't even continuous.

Comment: Oh yes! Good point.

Comment: One can take it even further and consider $f = \chi_{x\ne y}(1-\chi_{\mathbb Q^2}/2)$ that isn't continuous anywhere, but $f(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$.